# Difference between glcolor3b and glcolor3ub

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I was wondering what the difference is between `glcolor3b()` and `glcolor3ub()`.

It appears that `glcolor3b(255, 0, 0);` does not set the color to red, but rather it sets it to black. `glcolor3b(48, 160, 64)` sets it to dark purple, not green. `glcolor3ub()`, however works as expected.
Additionally, the documentation for [`glcolor3b()`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glColor3b%28byte,%20byte,%20byte%29) and [`glcolor3ub()`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glColor3ub%28byte,%20byte,%20byte%29) are exactly the same, except for the "u":

```
public static void glColor3(u)b(byte red,
              byte green,
              byte blue)
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: By the way, I would not call what you linked to documentation. That is basically looking at the function signature of something and trying to understand what it does, it usually does not work ;) Here is what [**real documentation**](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColor.xml) for those sets of functions looks like.

Comment: The link I gave was to the API documentation for that function in general. The C bindings for the language follow those documents verbatim, Java's bindings are slightly different for some of the functions that need things like "pointers."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glColor3b()` takes byte parameters with a range from **-128** to **127**.
`glColor3ub()` takes unsigned byte parameters with a range from **0** to **255**.
Using values greater than 127 with `glColor3b()` leads to an *arithmetic overflow*.

Answer (score 5):

Of course **255** sets it to black. That is **0xff** (or ***0b11111111***), which is **-1** using a 2's complement signed 8-bit number...

**-1** is less than **0**, which you would consider to be the absence of all color. Signed colors really do not make much sense outside of blending. In a nutshell, that is the difference between these two functions, one is signed and other is unsigned.

When you use the `glColor3b (...)` function (signed), then your range is **-128–127** (***-128*** maps to ***-1.0*** and ***127*** maps to ***1.0***, ***0*** is the mid-point),

When you use `glColor3ub (...)` function (**un**-signed), the range is **0–255** (***0*** maps to ***0.0*** and ***255*** maps to ***1.0***).

No matter which function you use, unless it is `glColor3f (...)`, they all do fixed-point to floating-point unit conversion. During fixed-point to floating-point normalization, the range of the integer data type is mapped directly between **-1.0** (signed) / **0** (unsigned) and **1.0**. The `u` vs. non-`u` simply indicates that one of them is unsigned (larger positive range).

Answer (score 2):

`glColor3ub` is the version for `unsigned char` in C/C++, that is a 8-bit integer without a sign.

`glColor3b` is the version for `char` which is a signed 8-bit integer.

255 = 0xFF is actually -1 when interpreted as a signed 8-bit integer. That is why you get a black screen because of the [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. Simply stick to the `ub` versions.