# Textures not rendering with lwjgl and vertex buffers

Tags: java, opengl, buffer, lwjgl, vbo

I have made several optimizations to the rendering code, but still, nothing renders, and all that is visible is a black window. It has worked before (with opengl immedieate mode rendering, but I seem to have broken the system.

Texture.java

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBBufferObject.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.util.ReadableColor;

public class Texture {

    public static Texture font1;

    public static Texture smallButton1;
    public static Texture smallButton1Hover;

    public static Texture background1;

    public static Texture title1;

    public static Texture smallTextBox1;
    public static Texture largeTextBox1;

    final String file;
    boolean loaded = false;
    private ByteBuffer buffer;
    public final int width, height;

    public static void loadTextures() {
        font1 = new Texture("/fonts/font1.png");

        background1 = new Texture("/textures/background1.png");

        title1 = new Texture("/textures/title1.png");

        smallButton1 = new Texture("/textures/smallButton1.png");
        smallButton1Hover = new Texture("/textures/smallButton1Hover.png");

        smallTextBox1 = new Texture("/textures/smallTextBox1.png");
        largeTextBox1 = new Texture("/textures/largeTextBox1.png");
    }

    public Texture(String path) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(TacAttack.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
            int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;
            int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
            image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

            buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * BYTES_PER_PIXEL); //4bytes for RGBA
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                    int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF)); // Red component
                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF)); // Green component
                    buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF)); // Blue component
                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF)); // Alpha component
                }
            }
            buffer.flip();

            loaded = true;

            System.out.println("Loaded texture: \"" + path + "\"");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ErrorHandler.fatalError(ErrorType.IOError, "Couldn't load texture: " + path);
        }

        this.file = path;

        this.width = image.getWidth();
        this.height = image.getHeight();
    }

    public ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
        if (!loaded) {
            ErrorHandler.fatalError(ErrorType.textureError, "Buffer requested before texture loaded.");
            return null;
        } else {
            return buffer;
        }
    }

    private void use(int texID, ReadableColor color) {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glColor4b(color.getRedByte(), color.getGreenByte(), color.getBlueByte(), color.getAlphaByte());
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    }

    private void endUse() {
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    public void render(int texID, IntBuffer vBuffer, FloatBuffer tBuffer, boolean changed, int vHandle, int tHandle, ReadableColor color) {
        if (!loaded) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(">>");
        System.out.println("apparently rendered at: x" + vBuffer.get(0) + ", y" + vBuffer.get(1) + ", w" + (vBuffer.get(4) - vBuffer.get(0)) + ", h" + (vBuffer.get(5) - vBuffer.get(1)) + " with vHandle - " + vHandle + ", " + file);
        System.out.println("apparent texturecoords: x" + tBuffer.get(0) + ", y" + tBuffer.get(1) + ", w" + (tBuffer.get(4) - tBuffer.get(0)) + ", h" + (tBuffer.get(5) - tBuffer.get(1)) + " with tHandle - " + tHandle);

        use(texID, color);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
        if (changed) {
            glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
            System.out.println("yeah");
        }
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, 2 * 4, 0L);

        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, tHandle);
        if (changed) {
            glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, tBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
            System.out.println("yeah2");
        }
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2 * 4, 0L);

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        endUse();
    }

}
```

TextureObject.java

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12;
import org.lwjgl.util.Color;
import org.lwjgl.util.ReadableColor;

public class TextureObject {

    private final Texture texture;

    public final int width, height;

    private final int texID;
    private IntBuffer vBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer tBuffer;

    private boolean changed = true;

    private IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2);
    private final int vHandle;
    private final int tHandle;

    public TextureObject(Texture texture) {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.width = texture.width;
        this.height = texture.height;

        texID = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

        //Setup wrap mode
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        //Setup texture scaling filtering
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        //Send tex data to OpenGL
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.getBuffer());

        vBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(8);
        tBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);
        vBuffer.put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0);
        tBuffer.put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0).put(0);

        glGenBuffersARB(ib);
        vHandle = ib.get(0);
        tHandle = ib.get(1);
    }

    public void render(int sx, int sy, int swidth, int sheight) {
        updateBuffers(sx, sy, swidth, sheight, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        texture.render(texID, vBuffer, tBuffer, changed, vHandle, tHandle, Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void render(int sx, int sy, int swidth, int sheight, ReadableColor color) {
        updateBuffers(sx, sy, swidth, sheight, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        texture.render(texID, vBuffer, tBuffer, changed, vHandle, tHandle, color);
    }

    public void render(int sx, int sy, int swidth, int sheight, float tx, float ty, float twidth, float theight) {
        updateBuffers(sx, sy, swidth, sheight, tx, ty, twidth, theight);
        texture.render(texID, vBuffer, tBuffer, changed, vHandle, tHandle, Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void render(int sx, int sy, int swidth, int sheight, float tx, float ty, float twidth, float theight, ReadableColor color) {
        updateBuffers(sx, sy, swidth, sheight, tx, ty, twidth, theight);
        texture.render(texID, vBuffer, tBuffer, changed, vHandle, tHandle, color);
    }

    private void updateBuffers(int sx, int sy, int swidth, int sheight, float tx, float ty, float twidth, float theight) {
        IntBuffer tempVertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(8);
        FloatBuffer tempTextureCoordsBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);

        tempVertexBuffer.clear();
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.clear();

        tempVertexBuffer.put(sx).put(sy);
        tempVertexBuffer.put(sx + swidth).put(sy);
        tempVertexBuffer.put(sx + swidth).put(sy + sheight);
        tempVertexBuffer.put(sx).put(sy + sheight);

        float ttx = tx / (float) texture.width;
        float tty = ty / (float) texture.height;
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.put(ttx).put(tty);
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.put(ttx + twidth).put(tty);
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.put(ttx + twidth).put(tty + theight);
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.put(ttx).put(tty + theight);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (vBuffer.get(i) != tempVertexBuffer.get(i)) {
                vBuffer.clear();
                tempVertexBuffer.flip();
                vBuffer.put(tempVertexBuffer);
                vBuffer.flip();
                changed = true;
                break;
            } else {
                changed = false;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (tBuffer.get(i) != tempTextureCoordsBuffer.get(i)) {
                tBuffer.clear();
                tempTextureCoordsBuffer.flip();
                tBuffer.put(tempTextureCoordsBuffer);
                tBuffer.flip();
                changed = true;
                break;
            } else {
                changed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All texture are rendered by calling "TextureObject.render(args)", and the console output from "Texture.render(args)" is all correct.

I get no errors, but nothing is rendering, so I suspect the texture itself somehow becomes a bunch of zeros.

Maybe this line from TextueObject.java?

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.getBuffer());
```

or related to this line?? :)

```
buffer.flip();
```

Haven't been able to figure this out for days...

Comment: Do you have a rendered quad without a texture? Or can you literally not see anything, not even the quad. (You can test this by calling immediate mode coloring before glDrawArrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after the great amount of time spent playing around with this, I should have known that the problem couldn't lie with the buffers.

The problem turned out to be this line from Texture.java:

```
glColor4b(color.getRedByte(), color.getGreenByte(), color.getBlueByte(), color.getAlphaByte());
```

which apparently set the color to black.

This, however, worked when I tried it (thanks to "Full Frontal Nudity" for helping me discover this):

```
glColor4f((float) color.getRed() / 255f, (float) color.getGreen() / 255f, (float) color.getBlue() / 255f, (float) color.getAlpha() / 255f);
```

It seems as though the bytes a ReadableColor returns is not the kind of bytes that lwjgl needs...

But, yay it works now!

Comment: Err, there is no need to do this. There was actually a [`similar question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577444/difference-between-glcolor3b-and-glcolor3ub) very recently. It boils down to `glColor4b (...)` using ***signed*** bytes. It has a range of **-128** - **127**. If you try to use an unsigned color, half of the color space will overflow if you pass it to the signed color function and will become negative. Negative colors are not useful in a lot of contexts, and when stored in the framebuffer will simply be replaced with 0 ;) -- In short, use `glColor4ub (...)`.